# Existence conditions of an expression with algebraic fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, fractions

I have to compute the existence conditions of the following expression:
$$\{\frac{3a^2}{x+2a}+[x^2:(1-\frac{a}{(x+a)})+a^2:(1-\frac{x}{(x+a)})]:\frac{(x^2+2ax+a^2)}{(x-2a)}\}:(\frac{(x^2-a^2)}{x^2}:\frac{(x^2-4a^2)}{x^2})=$$
$$=\{\frac{3a^2}{\color{red}{x+2a}}+[x^2:(\frac{\color{pink}x}{\color{green}{x+a}})+a^2:(\frac{\color{brown}a}{\color{green}{x+a}})]:\frac{(\color{violet}{x^2+2ax+a^2})}{(x-2a)}\}:(\frac{(\color{lightblue}{x^2-a^2})}{\bbox[yellow]{x^2}}:\frac{(\color{orange}{x^2-4a^2})}{\bbox[yellow]{x^2}})$$
Since all the fractions that appear have sense iff the denominator is zero and since I have to do some divisions ":", so I have thought:
$$\begin{cases} \color{red}{x+2a}\neq 0\\ \color{green}{x+a}\neq 0\\ \color{pink}x\neq 0\\ \color{brown}a\neq 0\\ \color{violet}{x^2+2ax+a^2}\neq 0 \\ x-2a\neq 0\\ \bbox[yellow]{x^2}\neq 0\\ \color{lightblue}{x^2-a^2}\neq 0\\\color{orange}{x^2-4a^2}\neq 0  \\ (\frac{(\color{lightblue}{x^2-a^2})}{\bbox[yellow]{x^2}}:\frac{(\color{orange}{x^2-4a^2})}{\bbox[yellow]{x^2}})\neq 0\iff (\frac{(\color{lightblue}{x^2-a^2})}{\bbox[yellow]{x^2}}\cdot \frac{(\bbox[yellow]{x^2})}{\color{orange}{x^2-4a^2}})\iff \color{lightblue}{x^2-a^2}\neq 0
\end{cases}$$ And so$$ \begin{cases}x\neq -2a\\ x\neq -a\\ x\neq 0\\ a\neq 0\\ x\neq 2a\\ x\neq a\\\end{cases}$$

Do you think my work is well done? Please can you help me? I don't know where I can check my work...

Comment: Maybe this should be tagged ([tag:solution-verification])? See [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info) for more information about this tag.

Comment: Thanks I will add this tag, hoping someone could answer!

Comment: Looks correct for me. The final conditions can be written a bit shorter. `x !=0;  |x| != |a|; |x|!= |2a|`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Ginsburg Yes I agree! Sp the fact thta I have imposedthat whatever object I will divide must be different from zero it is correct?

Comment: Not sure how did you get `a != 0`. This expression exists when `a = 0`.

Comment: Yes, you have to check that no denominator is equal to zero.

Comment: But when I divide by $(1-\frac{x}{x+a})=\frac{a}{x+a}$ I have to be sure thta $a$ is not zero, not?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg what do you think about the fact that a must be not $0$, looking at my previous comment?